# mod rewrite help needed to redirect old url to new

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

Basically I am trying to move all urls from this old url:

http://www.gamingonlinux.com/index.php?threads/crusader-kings-2-will-be-released-for-linux-today.1629/

To a new url (for all external links not working when i move my site to a new system)

http://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/crusader-kings-2-will-be-released-for-linux-today.1629

Could someone help me do that?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^/]+/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*   articles/%1?        [R=301,L]
```

Redirects permanently

`http://www.gamingonlinux.com/index.php?anything/query` with or without trailing slash

To:

`http://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/query`

Comment: How would i put this into a htaccess that already has a lot in it?

Comment: I would insert this rule-set either before of after the existing rules. But, try at the top first and insert all lines from the first `RewriteCond` to the `RewriteRule` in the rule-set of this answer, at the top of the .htaccess  file just below this line: `RewriteEngine On`. That way the new URL is processed by the other rules, but I am just guessing because can't test the other rules.

Comment: Tried adding before, tried after - either way it doesn't work it just send them to the index.php page? http://www.prxa.info/index.php?threads/heres-what-i-think-organ-trail-and-the-troubles-of-steam-greenlight.1615/ should go to http://www.prxa.info/articles/heres-what-i-think-organ-trail-and-the-troubles-of-steam-greenlight.1615 but it doesn't.

Comment: The reason is the other rules modify either the mapped or the incoming URL in/to the rule set in my answer, depending on it's location in the .htaccess file. All rules must be synchronized, which is not happening in this case, and shouldn't be modified (The original ones) if they are working fine.

Comment: Sorry to say but that just confused me? So can I get it to work or not?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work, in .htaccess in the main directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?threads/$1/ [L]
```

If it doesn't, there are tons of documents on mod_rewrite and regular expressions on Google and Bing!

*EDIT*: It was my understanding that you wanted the '/articles/' url to point to the 'index.php?thread' url. If I understand correctly, you want it to be the other way around, like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php?threads/([^/\.]+)/$ articles/$1 [L]
```

*EDIT2*: There was a bit of a problem, because of the question mark in the url. Everything after that becomes part of the QUERY_STRING instead of the url. I have tested the following piece of code, and it works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} threads/(.*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ articles/%1 [L]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That doesn't work, just incase you may have misread as i dont know how that code is supposed to work - im moving from one script to another so all old links i want to go to the new ones, so that index.php?threads no longer exists

Comment: @LiamDawe, I updated my answer, hopefully it works for you now.

Comment: Thanks but it still does nothing, with that exact code in place, here's a correct url right now for example http://www.prxa.info/articles/heres-what-i-think-organ-trail-and-the-troubles-of-steam-greenlight.1615 - if i try index.php?threads/<info> it doesnt redirect to the correct url

Comment: @LiamDawe, I updated my answer again, this time it should work! Please accept my answer if it does, as it was an annoying catch.